# c#,asp.net, zipping file takes long time and browser become ir-responsive

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I have images on my website where the user can download selected images. When the user selects more than one image the files are downloaded as zip files; the zipping process takes place on the server.

However, when the user selects more files( the size also increase let say by 500MB) so when he presses download the zipping starts on server. The web page is hanging and the user can't do anything until the zipping process has completed.

Sometimes the browser (like Chrome) gives messages (process is taking too long , kill this process). So I am looking for some help here.

I need a solid suggestion

Thanks

my code for zipping the file is:

```
public string Zip(string f, bool original)
{

    string zip = "";
    try
    {
        files = HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlDecode(files);
        string[] fileCollection = files.Split('*');
        zipFile = class1.zipfile(fileCollection, IsOriginal);


        int fileLength = files.Length;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception during processing {0}", ex);


    }
    return File;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three suggestions:

1. Show a busy screen on the client
   that lets the user know that he's
   waiting for a file download. You
   could achieve this i.e. by
   downloading to a separate iframe and
   checking the status of the iframe
   (for a dynamic approach see
   [Dynamically created iframe used to download file triggers onload with firebug but not without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456695/dynamically-created-iframe-used-to-download-file-triggers-onload-with-firebug-but))
2. Check how you actually zip the files - is compression required or do you just want to download all pictures
   together? Zipping with no
   compression is usually much faster.
3. If it still takes too long - even
   for a busy screen - consider using
   an asynchronous approach: A user may
   request a zip file with the images
   he/she selected, which causes the
   system to start processing the zip
   file. The user then may wait or come
   back to a dedicated page to check on
   the status of the zip file and, if
   it's ready, download it immediately
   from the server (i.e. from a virtual
   directory you put it after
   processing). This approach is a
   little more involved, also you have
   to think about cleanup.

Comment: @ broken Glass: for your suggestion number 2, I am using no compression. for suggestion number 1: I am using XSLT, AJAX, so you think that is good using your first suggestion?

Comment: @ Broken Glass: i have already done the clean up script for the file that are being zipped and downloaded, but now i am thinking about this asynchronous approach, dont you think if a user press download, so a new small window opens, and show him progress bar, that show him the progress for zipping up the files?

Comment: i cannot figure it out, can any one help me out?

Answer (score 2):

I would split off the zipping to a separate process (BackgroundWorker process?) and then update a status bar (AJAX) to keep the user informed of approximately how long it's going to take.

Comment: @safi, thinking about it, it may not be required.  I think @BrokenGlass has an excellent solution in using an iframe for status.  You may be able to set a session variable and read from that in the iframe that is doing the status updates.

Comment: @ Kendrick: I am waiting for that backgroundworker process. should i post the jcript also?

Comment: i HAVE TO USE the background worker and cute web ui progress bar.

Comment: Do you have access to modify the class1.zipFile function?  If so, you may be able to spawn a second thread in there and report progress back.  The issue with reporting progress with a BackgroundWorker thread is that you have to report the status from within the BackgroundWorker.DoWork event handler.  If you can add files to the .zip one at a time, and fire off a ProgressChanged event after each file is added, you're good to go.  If you can only send a list of files to the library, then you have an issue, no matter which method you'd like to use.  That is why I like @BrokenGlass's options best.