# Iframe.readyState does not work in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, iframe

I create an Iframe on the fly and set as the url a page that downloads a **binary file (xls, doc...).** While files are downloading I show an animation. When does not, I hide it.

The problem is that Chrome does not know when the files are fully downloaded, that is when the iframe is completely loaded. I use the iframe property `readyState` to check the iframe state:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.style.visibility = "hidden";
// I start a progress animation
window.setTimeout(showProgressAnimation, 1000);
// I start the file download
iframe.src ='GetFile.aspx?file=' + fileName;
document.body.appendChild(iframe);


function showProgressAnimation() {
   if (iframe.readyState == "complete" || iframe.readyState == "interactive") {
      // I stop the animation and show the page
      animation.style.display = 'none';
      progressBar.hide();
      $('#page').show();
   }
   else {
      // Chrome is always getting into this line
      window.setTimeout(showProgressAnimation, 1000);
   }
}
```

So the result is an infinite loop.

I've tried the following and it works in Firefox and Chrome **but not** when the contents are a binary file:

```
if ($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.webkit ) {
    iframe.onload = function showProgressAnimation() {
        animation.style.display = 'none';
        progressBar.hide();
        $('#page').show();
    }
}
// IE
else{
     window.setTimeout(showProgressAnimation, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I know that this is sound simple, but try to remove the `if ($.browser.mozilla) {` from the code and try it again. At least to me this is working. The `onload` is what I use and make it work.

Comment: why not   `$("iframe").on("load",function () {
        animation.style.display = 'none';
        progressBar.hide();
        $('#page').show();
    });` and does the console have something to say?

Comment: @Aristos I did it and doesn't work. Did you try with chrome? Question updated with the full cross browser code I have right now.

Comment: yes on Chrome, I use chrome. Did you get any errors ?

Comment: Do you see that you hide it with the `visible`, but you show it with the  `display` ? This must be the same to work. Place an alert on the `onload` to double check that is not called.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `onload` to signaling the load of the `iframe`

here is a simple example that working

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.style.display = "none";
// this function will called when the iframe loaded
iframe.onload = function (){
  iframe.style.display = "block";    
  alert("loaded");
};
// set the src last.
iframe.src ='http://www.test.com';

// add it to the page.
document.getElementById("one").appendChild(iframe);
```

Tested here:
http://jsfiddle.net/48MQW/5/
With `src` loaded last.
http://jsfiddle.net/48MQW/24/

Comment: Does not work in Chrome if url is a PDF or more accurately of mime type application/pdf. Works in IE 9, Windows Safari and FireFox. The versions are pretty much current for FF and Chrome. Safari is a few months old. Does work with http://www.test.com in all four.

Comment: @LeeMeador Thank you for the note. If you have a solution for the non-working case, please share it with us. The pdf is probably handle by the plugin of adobe acrobat and maybe this is make the issue of not working.

Comment: For the versions I have, it seems that FF and Chrome use their own code for PDF content. IE and Safari seem to use Acrobat plugins.

Comment: Just revisiting this, I believe strongly that you need to assign the onload before you set the src. Also why wrap the function in brackets?

Comment: @mplungjan ok, I will do that, sounds logical. No special reason the wrap with brackets.

Comment: Since onLoad event doesn't fire when downloading a file in Chrome, there's a technique that uses a cookie to check if it loaded or not. There's a plugin that implements that technique nicely: http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/

Comment: Does not work if content-disposition is attachment

Comment: @Nick because this is when you download a file - you can not know when you downloaded

Comment: @Aristos Then this is not really an answer to the original question is it?

Comment: @Nick after 10 years, I really don't remember. Now I see it again, its confuse me also. What I have write here is a way to auto make an iframe and know when its loaded. Not when a file is downloaded.

Answer (score 6):

The downloadable file content doesn't trigger the readystatechange event handler or the onload event handler. This couse you can set a cookie in server side together the file content, and client side check this cookie periodically. For example:

server

```
response.cookie('fileDownloaded','true');
response.header('attachment','your-file-name.any');
//...write bytes to response...
```

client

```
var checker = setInterval(()=>{
    if(document.cookie.indexOf('fileDownloaded')>-1){
        alert('done');
        clearInterval(checker);
    }
},100);
```

Of course, you can use your framework to check the cookie value correctly, this is just a poc, not a safe cookie parser.

Comment: I use this solution while downloading binary file from php script and the document.cookie never gets the value set in php, developer tools show correct set-cookie header but document.cookie is never updated.

Comment: `Set-Cookie:download=1518612276937` weird thing is that I have it in `cookie:` header in next request. It work like with httponly cookie but that option was not used. This is in Google Chrome. Maybe I'll ask another question.

Comment: Found the reason in comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download), if you use this solution you need to set the path for the cookie, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: But the cookie is set the same time when iframe completed loading (`iframe.contentDocumement.readyState == "complete"`) which just when first data is send to the client. (I'm using flush in php because otherwise I didn't get progrees in browser, only once at the end).

Answer (score 1):

Please try this - you are really mixing dom and jQuery from line to line

```
var tId;

function stopAnim() {
    // I stop the animation and show the page
    animation.hide();
    progressBar.hide();
    $('#page').show();
    clearInterval(tId);
}
var iframe = $("<iframe />");
iframe.css("visibility","hidden");

iframe.on("readystatechange",function() {
 if (this.readyState == "complete" || this.readyState == "interactive") {
   stopAnim();
 }
});
iframe.on("load",function() { // can possibly be deleted
 if (tId) {
   stopAnim();
 }
});

iframe.attr("src","GetFile.aspx?file=" + fileName);
$("body").append(iframe);
tId = setInterval(function() {
  // update progress here
}, 1000); //
```

Comment: If the URL loads a PDF (application/pdf) this does not work in FireFox or Chrome (where it takes the on-load option) but does work in Windows Safari. It works in IE 9 but prints twice (once for "interactive" and once for "complete") however the printed page is blank.

Comment: Why would an answer from 2012 be voted down in 2022? What kind of silliness is this?

Answer (score 0):

[Sarkiroka's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41104523/5211833) worked for me. I have added an instance `id` to the cookie name to provide a thread safe solution:

```
const instanceId = "some uuid retrieved from client";

response.cookie(`fileDownloaded-${instanceId}`,'true', { path: '/', secure: true, maxAge: 90000});
response.header('attachment','your-file-name.any');
//...write bytes to response...
```

client

```
var checker = setInterval(()=>{
    if(document.cookie.indexOf(`fileDownloaded-${instanceId}`)>-1){
        alert('done');
        clearInterval(checker);
    }
},100);
```