# iframe onload not working when url generates pdf ouput

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have one URL which generates PDF file. For generating PDF, i am using iframe to load that url and generate PDF file in same page for users.

When user click on button, it will show `loader` in screen. and it should be hide when iframe load complete(when PDF download popup). I used below code, but its not working, `loader` remain show after download popup open (if i change url with any other like google.com then it will work).

Here is my code snippet.

```js
$("#test").click(function(){
  iframe = document.getElementById("download-container1");
  if (iframe === null)
  {
    $("#ajax_loading").show();
    var url="http://test.coachfxlive.com/ajax/ajax-action.php?type=s&vid=0&playlist_id=11&perpage=1&action=get_profile";
    iframe = document.createElement('iframe');  
    iframe.id = "download-container1";
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);

    $('#download-container1').load(function () {
      $("#ajax_loading").hide();
    });
    iframe.src=url;
  }
  
});
```

```css
.ajax_loading {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="ajax_loading" id="ajax_loading"><span>Please Wait... Loading</span></div>
    <button id="test">click</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

When `iframe` complete load, need to hide div `ajax_loading`.
Am i doing anything wrong here? is there any other solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `readystate` iframe property to check if iframe is fully loaded. However this does not work in Chrome if contents is a binary file.

Once the iframe url is set it checks the iframe readystate property every second:

```
$("#test").click(function(){
 iframe = document.getElementById("download-container1");
 if (iframe === null)
 {
  $("#ajax_loading").show();
  var url="http://test.coachfxlive.com/ajax/ajax-action.php?type=s&vid=0&playlist_id=11&perpage=1&action=get_profile";
  iframe = document.createElement('iframe');  
  iframe.id = "download-container1";
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);

  //$('#download-container1').load(function () {
  //     $("#ajax_loading").hide();
  //});
  iframe.src=url;
  checkFinishedDownload(iframe);
}

 });

function checkFinishedDownload(ifr) {
     if (ifr.readyState == "complete" || ifr.readyState == "interactive") {
         // Here hide the spinner
         $("#ajax_loading").hide();
    }
     else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            checkFinishedDownload(ifr);
        }, 1000);
     }
}
 }
```

Check my question: [Iframe.readyState does not work in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952942/iframe-readystate-does-not-work-in-chrome)

**EDIT:**
In firefox you can use the `onload` event:

```
function checkFinishedDownload(ifr) {
     if ($.browser.mozilla) {
         ifr.onload = function () {
            $("#ajax_loading").hide();
          }

     }else{
          iframeCheck(ifr);
     }
}

function iframeCheck(iframe){
       if (iframe.readyState == "complete" || iframe.readyState == "interactive") {
         // Here hide the spinner
         $("#ajax_loading").hide();
    }
     else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            checkFinishedDownload(iframe);
        }, 1000);
     }
}
```

Comment: i tried same thing in firefox, but not worked for me.

Comment: please, check my edited answer. In firefox you have the `onload` event. You have to attach it over the iframe dom element.

Comment: is there any solution for safari and chrome?