# Catching iframe readystatechange event on the same origin URL

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, browser, onreadystatechange

On a web page, I tried to create a URL bar for a IFrame element(on the page) which URL is on the same origin.
I could catch 'load' event on iframe, but some page like phpmyadmin does not fire load event but fire Ready State Change event.
I tried to cache "readystatechange" event like below:

`var newFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
newFrame.setAttribute("src", url);
...
newFrame.addEventListener('load', function(){
    newFrame.contentDocument.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(ev){
        console.log('readystatechange', ev);
    });
});`

But, this does not work. I cannot catch the "readystatechange" event.
Is there any way to catch the "readystatechange" event of the iframe ?

Comment: "readystatechange" doesn't fire on all browsers. Did you get chance to see this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13954128/1759519

Comment: Thanks. And, sometimes, "load" event is not fired on clicking link...