# HTML form target iframe and iframe onreadystatechange event is not wroking chorme

Tags: javascript, html, forms, iframe, target

In this problem, I am submitting the form for downloading some documents. after submit i am showing IN-progress popup for loading as server is taking time for download process. Now the issue is after download documents loading popup is not hiding. I need download finished event so i can hide the loading popup.

```
    <iframe name="myiframe" onload="downloadFinished()" id="myiframe" style="display:none"
                                          src="javascript: <body></body>">

</iframe>

    <form name="myform" method="Post" target="myiframe">

    </form>
```

I tried so many fixes like onload,load, etc.. function. But i am not able to hide loader after finished downloaded file.

Comment: Earlier it was working fine with iframe onreadystatechange event.

Comment: Try `onbeforeunload`

Comment: Thanks for reply, but its not working 
    <iframe onbeforeunload="changeState(this)" id="myhiddenframe1" name="myhiddenframe1" style="display:none;"></iframe>

Comment: Post the code that invokes popup

Comment: function downloadFilteredFiles() {  
            ProgressPopupshow("Processing request...");
      document.myHiddenForm.submit(); 
     }

Comment: There's more to it than that if this is a plugin you should read the documentation

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I got the solution from below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952942/iframe-readystate-does-not-work-in-chrome/41104523#41104523