# How can I know if the client has finished downloading a file

Tags: java, http, client-server, download, fileutils

In my web application clients can download files from the server.
My code looks a bit like this:

```
public void downloadFile(HttpServletResponse response, String fileName){
       File fileToDownload = getFileWithName(fileName);
       updateContentTypeAndLength(response);
       OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
       FileUtils.copyFile(fileToDownload, out);
}
```

The thing is I need to know when the client has finished downloading the file, is there a way for me to know that?
Thanks.

Comment: That seems to be responsibility of client side. How you are requesting ?

Comment: Well they can't download it faster than you are sending it, so some time after the `copyFile` method call returns.

Comment: What is it you want to do?

Comment: might helpful :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524639/how-to-trigger-onload-event-when-downloading-a-file-in-an-iframe

Comment: My intention is to be as sure as I can that the client did get the file (totally downloaded it).
I'm pretty sure that once this 'FileUtils.copyFile(fileToDownload, out);' is over - it does not mean that the client did finished downloading this file.

Answer (score 0):

if the method finished ,and don't have any error,you should know the client have finished the downloading file. or you can return a status to client.