# SRC attributes in IFRAME change with onload function

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

if I have the "src" attributes in IFRAME change is the "onload" Function not executed. It works ONLY when first called.

JavaScript:

```
function dialog () {
    document.getElementById('result').src = "myurl";
}

function loading() {
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('result').style.display = "block";
}
```

---

HTML:

```
<div id="loading"><img src="loading.gif"/></div>
<iframe style="display:none;" id="result" onload="loading();" src="myurl"/></iframe>
```

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524639/how-to-trigger-onload-event-when-downloading-a-file-in-an-iframe

Comment: The problem I grab is within and outside of frame src attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your page domain and iframe domain the same? If they are different you can use [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) to access iframe events.

---

EDIT

```
<script>

    function dialog() {
        document.getElementById('result').src = "http://jsfiddle.net";
    }
    function loading() {
        alert('Loading finished');
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('result').style.display = "block";
    }

</script>

<div id="loading">Loading</div>
<iframe  style="display:none;" id="result" onload="loading();" src="http://jsfiddle.net"/>
```

It works, live demo -- http://jsfiddle.net/xf2LgLsg/
I believe you write JS after HTML, so this may be a problem.

Comment: yes, it is the same domain. I change the SRC attribute within the iframe and Outside.

Comment: Edited my answer with tested solution.

Comment: <input type="button" onclick="dialog('ebay.com');" value="send"> and change function dialog() to dialog(params). Not working!

Comment: If you try to load `ebay.com` you have to run that script on ebay.com domain, or use CORS.