# HTTP form submit callback

Tags: javascript, html

I'm posting a form that causes a file to be downloaded. So my browser page does not change. My form is e.g. `form action="/download/file.txt"`. I'm aware that I could use JQuery and download the file with AJAX and use the JQuery callback mechanisms. However, I don't want to use JQuery because this is a learning experience. Is there any way to call a Javascript function when my file has downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this without AJAX. So either you use JQuery's AJAX call, or just plain JS, and use the onreadystatechange event (http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp). There is no JS event you can trigger when the submit is "completed" by setting it as an attribute on the form (like onClick="" etc).

So plain JS is possible with AJAX, but you'd just be making it yourself harder

Comment: If you use XMLHttpRequest, the file won't be downloaded, it will be put into a Javascript variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<form action="nextStep.php" onsubmit = "return function(){
                 //download the file here **download/file.txt**
                 //if(downloaded == successful)
                 // set the flag as true
                 //else
                 // set the flas as false

}" >
```

if it is good then go the **nextStep.php** file

Answer (score 0):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524639/how-to-trigger-onload-event-when-downloading-a-file-in-an-iframe) uses an iframe to load the static file and get the notification in its onload event. You can check the same.